# iPhone static UITableView: how to place two cells in a single row?

Tags: ios, uitableview, addressbookui

Preferences dialogs and item entry views on iOS seem to usually be build as static UITableViews in style UITableViewStyleGrouped. Their design is consistent over all dialogs of the built in apps.

However, there is one place that differs and that I would like to imitate in my app: the contact edit view of the address book. I refer to the placement of the contact photo on the left side with having name and company entries on the right side of the same section.

However, there seems to be no way to modify the horizontal placement of UITableViewCells on the UITableView. How might Apple have done this?

A screenshot (in German unfortunately) showing the respective part of the iPhone address book can be found on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/95q7n.png

Comment: It's a custom cell with two labels side by side, and maybe some custom drawing to put the line in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Those are actually just one cell but a vertical line has been added to create that illusion that you can easily draw in your cell yourself as below:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0,0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 20);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

If you do really want two cells placed next toe each other horizontally, you can leverage a framework such as [PrettyKit](https://github.com/vicpenap/PrettyKit) that easily allows you to do just that!

Hope this helps :)